# What is meant by src in Java Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

What is meant by the src in Eclipse IDE?

Also what are all the default packages/components/classes created by the eclipse IDE for us?

Answer (score 6):

You mean the `src` folder? It's short for "source", it's where the source code files are stored. When it compiles it stores the class files in `bin`

Answer (score 5):

The word 'src' is a common abbreviation for 'source' ... e.g. a project's source code.

In an Eclipse project 'src' is a common default folder name for a project's source code ... though it depends on how the Eclipse project was created or instantiated.  For example, the 'src' name in a Maven-based project comes from the default Maven project structure.

> Also what are all the default packages/components/classes created by the eclipse IDE for us?

For a typical Eclipse project, Eclipse does not create any default packages, components or classes.  Some non-generic Eclipse project creation wizards may generate  stuff, but it doesn't make sense to enumerate all possible behaviors of all possible wizards.  Check the documentation for the wizard you are using ...